# Azure ADLS Gen2 File read using Python (without ADB)

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Want to read files(csv or json) from ADLS gen2 Azure storage using python(without ADB) .

```py
file  = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_string,file_system_name="test", file_path="source")

with open("./test.csv", "r") as my_file:
    file_data = file.read_file(stream=my_file)
```

Error :
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'DataLakeFileClient' object has no attribute 'read_file'

My try is to read csv files from ADLS gen2  and convert them into json. Download.readall() is also throwing the ValueError: This pipeline didn't have the RawDeserializer policy; can't deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below piece of code and see if it resolves the error:

```py
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=*****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test")

directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("testdirectory")

file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("test.txt")

download=file_client.download_file()

downloaded_bytes = download.readall()

with open("./sample.txt", "wb") as my_file:
    my_file.write(downloaded_bytes)
    my_file.close()
```

Also, please refer to this [Use Python to manage directories and files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python)  MSFT doc for more information.